# FRV case, accomodation document for spouse visa Germany

Tags: visa, germany, family

Help , Please

I applied for bluecard visa and my wife on FRV on the same day of my appointment in Islamabad embassy.

Visa officer said all the docs are ok just one doc is required for your wife FRV application, they said to send us proof of accomodation for wife via email.

Now my company has sent me a document which clearly states both of us along with passport numbers that company is responsible for managing the accomodation for us and apartment is located on xyz street.

Will this document be enough for now to fullfil their requirements for proof of accomodation or i will also need to send the any hotel contract as well.

Some people said this document is enough since company is taking the responsibility and no need to send the hotel contract instead.

After sending this doc i also received a response next day that we have received this document and will be added to her file for further processing.

Please guide as per the best of your knowledge, anyone who can guide please.

Comment: Seems likely the visa officer would contact you again if the document isn’t sufficient.